# Можно ли изменять свойства материала только для одного объекта в Unity

Tags: unity3d-editor

Для текстуры кнопки используется материал Button. Кнопок на уровне довольно много. Я хочу, чтобы при нажатии кнопки она, например, загоралась красным. Можно ли изменить, например, эмиссию материала только для одного объекта? Если да, то как получить доступ к свойствам материала? Если нет - нет. ^w^

Comment: можно назначить ей другой материал

Comment: Можно через скрипт. загугли как динамически изменять/редактировать материал через скрипт

Comment: Например я изменял материал персонажа через скрипт вот так: gameObject.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().materials[0].color = color;